# start 2 timers simultaneously in a matlab function

Tags: matlab, timer

I have a program with 2 timer functions like this (`p_maj_input` and `p_maj_output_motion` are equal so the period of both timer is the same):

```
maj_input = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period',p_maj_input,'TasksToExecute', ...
    floor(Tmeasurement/p_maj_input)-1,'TimerFcn',{@time_append,p_maj_input,HR_all,freq_HR, ...
    BVP_all,freq_BVP,TEMP_all,freq_TEMP,ACC_x_all,ACC_y_all,ACC_z_all,freq_ACC,EDA_all,freq_EDA, ...
    folder_all,all_dir,num_dir}); start(maj_input);

maj_output_motion=timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period',p_maj_output_motion,'TasksToExecute', ...
    floor(Tmeasurement/p_maj_output_motion)-1,'TimerFcn',{@output_motion_append, ...
    freq_MOTION,freq_mvt_score,freq_walk,p_maj_output_motion,p_maj_output_walk,folder_all,all_dir,num_dir});%,'StartDelay',min(5,p_maj_output_motion)); %startDelay must be min 5 for walk detection start(maj_output_motion);
```

In each timer callback function there is a loop over subfolders contained in a folder that is selected at the beginning of the program.

```
output_motion_append(obj,event,freq_MOTION,freq_mvt_score,freq_walk,p_maj_output_motion,p_maj_output_walk,folder_all,all_dir,num_dir)
    fprintf('motion %d\n',obj.TasksExecuted)
    toc
    for folder_index=1:num_dir
        [folder_original,folder_fictive] = subfolderFunction(all_dir, folder_all, folder_index);
        fileName=strcat(folder_fictive,'\ACC.csv');
        [ACC_time, ACC_x, ACC_y, ACC_z] = loadValuesE4_acc(fileName);
       
% Motion Amount        
        [agitation,agitation_ts] = identifyAgitation(ACC_x,ACC_y,ACC_z,ACC_time);
        agitation=agitation';

        len1=length(agitation);
        if len1<=freq_MOTION*p_maj_output_motion
            i_init1=1;
        elseif len1>freq_MOTION*p_maj_output_motion
            i_init1=len1-freq_MOTION*p_maj_output_motion+1;
        end
        
        writematrix([agitation(i_init1:len1)],strcat(folder_fictive,'\MOTION_output.csv'),'WriteMode','Append');
        
     writematrix([mvt_score(i_init2:len2)],strcat(folder_fictive,'\neurologicScore_output.csv'),'WriteMode','Append');

    end
    
end
```

Everything works fine if the number of subfolders is lower than 4 : the good values appear in the files on which is carried out the `writematrix` function. And the timer callback function are are called one after the other, so both timer work simultaneously.
However if there are 5 subfolders or more, it is not the good values and using the debugging I noticed that the first callback function is triggered the number of 'TasksToExecute', and then only the second callback function seems to be called. That is to say the 2 timers don't work simultaneously.

I have tried to increase `p_maj_input` and `p_maj_output_motion` to see if the problem is that matlab can't finish to run before another timer callback function is called but still for 5 subfolders I get the same problem.

Does anyone know where my problem is coming from?

Comment: If you need to run code in parallel, use the [Parallel Computing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing.html). Outside of that, code is always sequential. Timer callbacks triggered at the same time will run one after another because the MATLAB engine is sequential in nature.

Comment: it is not a problem if there run one after the other. But let's imagine if for instant callback function 1 prints "c1" in the command window and callback function 2 prints "c2". When I run my algorithm and that less that there are 4 subfolders, i get in the command window : C1, C2, C1, C2... That is what I want. However if there 5 subfolders, I get C1, C1, C1, C1 ... C2, C2, C2, C2..., and this happen even if I increase the Period parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior occurs because one timer hasn't finished executing by the time it triggers again, so the second timer never has a chance to execute until the first timer is finished.  If you change the ExecutionMode from 'fixedRate' to 'fixedSpacing', then you'll guarantee that there's time for the second timer to execute.

```
function duelingTimers()
disp('With ExecutionMode = fixedRate')
t1 = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period',0.1,'TasksToExecute',5,'TimerFcn',@timerFcn1);
t2 = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period',0.1,'TasksToExecute',5,'TimerFcn',@timerFcn2);
cleanup = onCleanup(@()delete([t1,t2]));

    function timerFcn1(~,~)
        pause(0.2)
        disp('Timer 1');
    end
    function timerFcn2(~,~)
        pause(0.2)
        disp('Timer 2');
    end

start(t1),start(t2)

wait(t1)
wait(t2)

disp(newline)
disp('With ExecutionMode = fixedSpacing')
t1.ExecutionMode = 'fixedSpacing';
t2.ExecutionMode = 'fixedSpacing';

start(t1),start(t2)

wait(t1)
wait(t2)
end
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked very well by just changing the ExecutionMode !